# Cannot find datadog agent connected to elasticserch

Tags: elasticsearch, monitoring, datadog

I have an issue where i have multiple host dashboards for the same elasticsearch server. Both dashboards has its own name and way of collecting data. One is connected to the installed datadog-agent and the other is somehow connected to the elasticsearch service directly.
The weird thing is that i cannot seem to find a way to turn off the agent connected directly to the ES service, other than turning off the elasticsearch service completly.

I have tried to delete the datadog-agent completely. This stops the dashboard connected to it, to stop receiving data (of course) but the other dashboard keeps receiving data somehow. I cannot find what is sending this data and therefor is not able to stop it. We have multiple master and data node and this is an issue for all of them. ES version is 7.17

another of our clusters is running ES 6.8, and we have not made the final configuration of the monitoring of this cluster but for now it does not have this issue.

just as extra information:
The dashboard connected to the agent is called the same as the host server name, while the other only has the internal ip as it's host name.

Does anyone have any idea what it is that is running and how to stop it? I have tried almost everything i could think of.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the reason. as all datadog-agents on all master and data nodes was configured to not use the node name as the name and cluster stats was turned on for the elastic plugin for datadog. This resulted in the behavior that when even one of the datadog-agents in the cluster was running, data was coming in to the dashboard which was not named correclty. Leaving the answer here if anyone hits the same situation in the future.